# jQuery inside asp:UpdatePanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a `MultiView` inside an `UpdatePanel` and a jQuery that transforms that content for each `View` inside my `MultiView`, my java-script code is outside the `UpdatePanel`, problem is that I want to have a custom variable from the code behind inside my java-script like here:

```
<script>
    function Foo(){
       var a = <%=this.MyVariable%>
       ...
    }
$(document).ready(Foo);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(Foo);
</script>
```

this only works (my variable changes) if I have my `script` inside my UpdatePanel like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <script>
        function Foo(){
           var a = <%=this.MyVariable%>
           ...
        }
    $(document).ready(Foo);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(Foo);
    </script>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem is that the jQuery dosn't executes correct, it uses the last `variable a` content.
If I use Google Chrome Developer Tools I can see that in `Elements` tab the java-script is updated with the correct `variable a` but in the `Sources` tab `variable a`is not updated.

Is there a step that I did't do, or another way to achieve this ?

Thanks.